# Error Using RelativeSource FindAncestor in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, relativesource

I do have an Window (DataContext VM) and a Listview (ItemSource Observable List in VM)
Data comes from an sqlite DB, the Observable List is Type of Model, representing Residents.
Each Resident should have an "CheckIn" or "CheckOut" Button, for them, i do have ICommands in my VM.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Oc_BewohnerList}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Name:" Width="50"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nachname, StringFormat={}{0}\, }" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                    <Button Content="Check In" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:BewohnerVM}}, Path=CheckInCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
```

Why do i get an Error "Die Eigenschaft "CheckInCommand" wurde im Objekt vom Typ "RelativeSource" nicht gefunden." That the CheckInCommand is not found?

I did it first with Xamarin.Forms and there it worked in a similiar way ... i cant find a solution myself, tried tons of combinations for realtivesource and ancestorlevel ...

Thx in advance
Nala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely just a small syntax error and you want (note the double usage of `RelativeSource` , once as a property of Binding once as MarkupExtension...)

EDIT and also the AncestorType should be an UIElement, whose DataContext exposes that CheckInCommand.

```
<Button Content="Check In" 
     Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.(viewModels:BewohnerVM.CheckInCommand)}"
     CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunatly not. This is one of the things i tried alrdy - still getting an error 
DataContext: null
Description: Quelle nicht gefunden: RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='IWHRManagment.ViewModels.BewohnerVM', AncestorLevel='1'

Comment: Actually I think one error is using `Source={RelativeSource` instead of `RelativeSource={RelativeSource` The other is specifying the VMType as `AncestorType`, where a UIElement (probably the ListView) is expected.

Comment: I tried the solution @Andy provided without success, he said somtehing similar

Comment: @lidqy Sorry, saw your edit too late - the Solution with your edit works like a charm - i just dont understand it right now :D

Comment: Hi @Nala thx for the feedback&glad it works.
My solution is just a combination of both issues. And there is kind of a cast contained which might look unusual in XAML, I mean this `Path=DataContext.(viewModels:BewohnerVM.CheckInCommand)`. It just tells the parser&designer to cast the DataContext to 'BewohnerVM' and then access the 'CheckInCommand'. It does just the same as 'Path=DataContext.CheckInCommand',

Answer (score 3):

A relativesource binding is up the visual tree.
As in controls not viewmodels.
You're not going to be looking for a viewmodel.
If the command is a property on VM and that's the datacontext of the window then the ListView inherits that datacontext.

You've not explained everything but I think you need more like:

```
<Button Content="Check In" 
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, 
Path=DataContext.CheckInCommand}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunatly still "no" :(
DataContext: RelativeSource
Description: Die Eigenschaft "DataContext" wurde im Objekt vom Typ "RelativeSource" nicht gefunden.

What information do you need to ?

`public class BewohnerVM : INotifyPropertyChanged

    {
       
      public ICommand CheckInCommand { get; set; }`

Comment: You likely should fix both, the ReleativeSource vs Source thing and the 'AncestorType=ListView}}, Path=DateContext.CheckInCommand' thingy.

Comment: @user2867797 This was the first correct answer to the posted question.